# Sublime Text 2 package to add ; automatically on enter press

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When you write eg. console.log("whatevs") and your cursor is placed before ") I want to bind a key-combination to add ; and then return.

Yeah, u can make a macro to achieve this, or a snippet for console log with right placed tabs.
But if this is python and i want to add : or some other language?

So i started to write a small plugin. 
But I cant find out how to know what type of file I'm editing. Maybe i missed it in the [documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference).

My question is: Is there already a plugin to achieve this, is there a more detailed documentation somwwhere or maybe someone knows about this and can get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LewisW/SublimeAutoSemiColon Is almost what you want. It makes it so if your cursor is between the () and you press ; it will auto jump to the end of the line and add it there.

You could check out the source for that too for a base to work off to create exactly what you want.